# Build working for xCode but nor in app store ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, appstore-approval

red alert my app has been rejected from app review team,

that's simple the app perfectly work on severals devices when i build from Xcode, but not when the app is build for the app store it does not work, the app starts but get stuck on first instructions.

I load a plist from my server, i use ASIHTTPRequest to get it, but when i build for the app store (ad hoc)

i get my file using :

```
 NSURL *anUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer/myFile.plist"];
   __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:anUrl];


    Reachability *aReachObject = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];


    if (aReachObject.isReachable)
    {

        [request startAsynchronous];


        [request setCompletionBlock:^{

           // DO STUFF WITH DATA HERE
}];
```

This request never starts, so the app never load and cannot correctly get launch. 
I know it is an old way to do but i have use this in all my project, i do not know what to do please someone help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I had a similar problem (although it wasn't rejected by the app team, they let it pass anyway...it was awful).  Are you sure your server is accessible from outside your internal network?

Comment: Absolutely sure the app works perfectly when i build from my xcode project, they have rejected because the app does not start !

Comment: That's why I asked *from outside your internal network*.  When you build with Xcode, then I am guessing you are using your internal network to connect to the server.  Maybe the firewalls are getting in the way, etc?  Can you tether from 3G or something to try it out that way?

Comment: Yea sorry 3G Edge, my Wifi, even worked on our neighbor  wifi ! I wanna cry

Comment: How about this.  What happens when the network is off?

Comment: IT works, because i have handle the case where network is off, then i propose the user to press a button to start the request and the request perfectly works this time ! i do not understand why.